# Pipdrive Create a new deal from Email

Tags: pipedrive-api

We have an existing quotation system which we use to generate our quote in PDF form. How do I configure pipedrive to receive these email as a cc or bcc to enable us to keep track of all the quotes going out with their email body & attachment?

Example: In trello each track has a unique "trello" email address - hence when I email to there it automatically creates the card, I would like to the same in pipedrive

Your assistance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant by "keep track of all the quotes". You want this external PDF to somehow affect Pipedrive?

You could try Zapier integration like
https://zapier.com/app/editor/template/10394

That would generate deal based on email..

I suggest you contact Pipedrive support or provide more technical details what you tried or what you expect